# How to work with API that requires a callback function as query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to work with the API here: https://abr.business.gov.au/json/ but it requires a callback function to be passed in as a query parameter. How can I actually use this API from a react app and pass in a callback function?

I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The API calls return some javascript.

So when you make the following request:

```
https://abr.business.gov.au/json/AbnDetails.aspx?abn=74172177893&callback=callback&guid=myguid
```

It will return this:

```
callback({"Abn":"","AbnStatus":"","Acn":"","AddressDate":null,"AddressPostcode":"","AddressState":"","BusinessName":[],"EntityName":"","EntityTypeCode":"","EntityTypeName":"","Gst":null,"Message":"The GUID entered is not recognised as a Registered Party"})
```

This will invoke a function on the window object named `callback`, so somewhere in your code you have to define a function named `callback` which handles the call.

Here is an example of it being done for the request where `callback=abnCallback`, note the `abnCallback` function: https://abr.business.gov.au/json/Script/abnlookup-sample.js

Good luck, this doesn't really have anything to do with react btw. It's just a javascript thing.

Comment: So I send a request like this ```fetch(`${abnAddress}?guid=${GUID}&abn=${abnNo}&callback=callbackFunction`, {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })```  and i've got a function ```const callbackFunction = (e) => {
    console.log('call back func')
    setCallBack(e)
  }```  that should get called? But I can't see the console.log anywhere in my localhost. How can I get the results of the callback function into my app?

Comment: Don't say `const callbackFunction = ...`. Say `window.callbackFunction = ...`

Comment: @Ogen Let's say i'm not using a scripting language and I'm calling this endpoint. Is there any recommended way to extract the json object instead of the function call?

Comment: @LakshanThilakarathne regexp and JSON.parse. :)